# I get an error in my flutter when i click on a button

Tags: flutter

This is the error:

> Tried to call Provider.of. This is likely a mistake and is
> therefore unsupported. If you want to expose a variable that can be
> anything, consider changing `dynamic` to `Object` instead.
> 'package:provider/src/provider.dart': Failed assertion: line 304 pos
> 7: 'T != dynamic'

**Here is the code :**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:lms/Food/screens/landingPage.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'notifiers/authNotifier.dart';

// void main() {
//   runApp(MyApp());
// }

void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(
    providers: [
      ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => AuthNotifier(),
      ),

    ],
       child: Consumer<AuthNotifier>(
  builder: (context, counter, child) {
          return MaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: 'Cassia',
            theme: ThemeData(
              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
              primaryColor: Color.fromRGBO(255, 63, 111, 1),
            ),
            home: FoodMain(),
          );
        }
  )));
}

class FoodMain extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: context.watch().LandingPage<AuthNotifier>(),
    );
  }
}
```